# Error finding least common ancestor of Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am working on the following question for class:

> Find the least common ancestor between two nodes on a binary search
>   tree.

I have turned in the following code and was informed that it is not working correctly, even though I thought I had everything worked out correctly. Could someone please provide insight as to what I am doing wrong?

```
# Main Function.
def Question4(T, r, n1, n2):
    # Compare values of n1, n2, in relation to r to find LCA.
    while not n1 <= r <= n2:
        r = r if n1 <= r else r
    # return LCA.
    return r

# Test Cases.
T = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
r = 3
p = 1
q = 4
print ("Least Common Ancestor is:", Question4(T, r, p, q))
# Least Common Ancestor:
# 3
```

Comment: What is T, r, n1 and n2? Those are cryptic variable names, can you at least describe them?

Comment: The code makes no sense (it either returns `r` or doesn't terminate), so I guess it has never been run on even a single test case. What steps did you perform to check that "everything is working correctly"?

Comment: Yes sorry, `T` Represents the tree `r` the root, and `n1, n2` represent two nodes. Though as siamezzze stated below I think I'm lacking the fundamental concept of how to solve this question. So likely I will need to re-write it.

Comment: @Paul Hankin. I had test cases like the ones printed at the end of my code but as clarified by the accepted answer they are just returning r as the root, so I will have to rewrite this code after rethinking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the quick glance:

1. Your function does not use T at all. Whatever is stored here, this information just goes unnoticed.
2. `r` value never even changes, so your function either return the initial `r` value or is stuck in the endless `while` loop if its condition is met.

With that being said, it is unclear what you were even planning to do in there, so I'm unable to assist you further. Try addressing these problems and  see where it leads you.